# Wordpress contact form 7 redirect user to specific page based on entry in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make a contact form that sends the user to a new 'hidden' page based on his entry in the drop down.

My contact form looks like this:

```
I'm interested in:
[select subject id:subject "Construction" "Professional Services" "Financial Services" "Wholesale" "IT & Telecom" "Industry" "Transport & Logistics"]

Leave your e-mail address to unlock more information about your preferred subject:
[email* your-email]

[submit "Send"]
```

What I want the form to do is when a user selects 'Construction', enters his e-mail address and submits the form, he will be directed to 'www.example.com/construction/', and the same for the other options in the drop down, all with their own url.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set an array of answers that result in which URLs and then redirect on submit

Comment: Thanks, I'm not that pro with javascript, can you tell me what code I can use for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different value redirecting to different URLs after successful submission.

**Example:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".wpcf7").on( 'mailsent.wpcf7', function(){
        var redirect_to = $(this).find('#subject').val();  // Enter your drop-down id
        if( typeof(redirect_to)!=='undefined' && redirect_to!='' ){
            window.location.href= redirect_to;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain where I need to place this code and where in the code I need to put the id of the drop-down and the different url's?

Comment: @JSBdesign I have updated my answer.  Would you please put this code in your `footer.php`?

Comment: thanks. But I still don't really get it. Where in the code do I need to put the drop-down id (where in that line you indicated), and do I have to put the url's anywhere in this code?

Answer (score 0):

This code logic below should get you close. You may have to take it apart a little and refactor, but that'll help you understand it better anyways. Here is the live [demo](http://output.jsbin.com/ifupix/1). G'luck!

```
  <form onSubmit="return checkAnswer();">
  <input id="answer" type="text" maxlength="55" class="box" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
  <script>
  function checkAnswer(){
      var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
      if (response == "correctanswer")
          location = 'http://www.correcturl.com';
      else
          location = 'http://www.wrongurl.com';
      return false;
  }
  </script>
```